# Shortest path from source to destination with constant number of negative edges.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

You are given a directed graph G where all edge lengths are positive except for one
edge. Given a source vertex s, give O(mlogn) time algorithm for finding a shortest
path from a vertex s to a vertex t. Now assume there are a constant number of edges in
G which have negative weights (rest have positive weights). Give an O(mlogn) time
algorithm to find a shortest path from s to t.

I have found the solution if it consists of only one negative edge.

**My solution-**

1. Find the negative weight using BFS/DFS lets say (u,v).

   - Find the shortest path from source to u using Dijkstra
   - Find the shortest path from v to destination  using Dijkstra.
   - shortest path from source and destination =shortest path from source to u + shortest path from
     v to destination + weight of edge(u,v)

Time Complexity will be O(mlogn)

But I am not able to figure out for some constant number of negative edges.

Comment: Relative to your algorithm.  If $s \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow u$ has weight $100$, $u \rightarrow v$ has weight $-1$, and $v \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow t$ has weight $100$, while at the same time the edge $s \rightarrow t$ has weight $1$, your algorithm has not found the shortest path from $s$ to $t$.  You should also consider finding the shortest path in the graph $G$ without the edge between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @EricTowers We need to also check explicitly from s-t then any path exist without considering u-v edge. Then my algorithm is correct or not?

Comment: Usually "path" in a graph does not permit an edge appearing more than once.  However, usage has not been standardized long enough that I can guarantee your use of the term has this constraint.  Does your definition of "path" in a graph allow the path to traverse the negative weight edge more than once?

Comment: @EricTowers"path' in a graph allowed to traverse the negative edge once only. I mean to say we apply dijkstra in  the purest form in original graph  and then considering my first solution. Taking the minimum of both cases will be the answer.

Comment: The shortest path from the source to $u$ might have edges in common with the shortest path from $v$ to the destination. So your solution might return a *walk* instead of a *path*.